# Spec - How to edit the contents of a table in place

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have an `SpTablePresenter` and I would like to edit the cell contents.
In many frameworks it is possible to edit the contents of a table directly in place, without needing to open a new component (dialog or master-detail style). How can I do this with Spec ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Tables and tree tables in Spec inplement a mechanism to edit string columns in place

in Spec, string columns can be edited by just declaring the column to be editable sending the `beEditable` message and adding a callback to process the edition by sending `onAcceptEdition:`, which receives two parameters, the object being editing and the edited string.

The following code will show how this can be done:

```
app := SpApplication new.
app useBackend: #Gtk.
 
presenter := SpPresenter new.
presenter application: app.

presenter layout: (SpBoxLayout newTopToBottom
    add: (tablePresenter := presenter newTable);
    yourself).

tablePresenter 
    addColumn: (SpStringTableColumn title: 'R/O' evaluated: #key);
    addColumn: ((SpStringTableColumn 
            title: 'Editable' 
            evaluated: #value)
        beEditable; 
        onAcceptEdition: [ :anAssociation :aString | anAssociation value: aString ];
        yourself).

tablePresenter items: { 1 -> 'One'. 2 -> 'Two'. 3 -> 'Three' }.
    
presenter asWindow 
    title: 'Example editing cells';
    open
```

This will produce (with the Gtk3 backend) this output:

[image: example edit in place]